# jboss hangs up for long time after starting PersistenceUnitDeployment

Tags: jboss, garbage-collection, persistence

I see the following texts on jboss console when I start it. The reason seems to be due to garbace collection. That was not happening before. I havent changed any neither any configuration files nor any of the source codes.  Any ideas to resolve?
As you can see I'm waiting nearly (12:37 - 12:21) 16 minutes in between after it starts the persistence part.

```
12:21:53,438 INFO  [PersistenceUnitDeployment] Starting persistence unit persistence.units:ear=ikarus.ear,unitName=ikarus
36.473: [GC 74716K->29865K(241856K), 0.0153986 secs]
37.818: [GC 75689K->35101K(240896K), 0.0124849 secs]
40.876: [GC 80925K->37018K(242304K), 0.0124359 secs]
41.176: [GC 84186K->38778K(241792K), 0.0096731 secs]
41.481: [GC 85946K->40591K(241152K), 0.0166358 secs]
41.621: [GC 86863K->43877K(241600K), 0.0127246 secs]
93.771: [GC 90149K->46121K(241856K), 0.0080522 secs]
324.787: [GC 92777K->46313K(241728K), 0.0025572 secs]
534.417: [GC 92804K->46457K(241920K), 0.0012326 secs]
788.777: [GC 93241K->46677K(241792K), 0.0017520 secs]
907.338: [GC 72305K->46805K(242688K), 0.0030763 secs]
907.342: [Full GC 46805K->46781K(242688K), 0.1523979 secs]
12:37:02,786 INFO  [JmxKernelAbstraction] creating wrapper delegate for: org.jboss.ejb3.entity.PersistenceUnitDeployment
```

Answer (score 0):

Take some **thread dumps** in between to see what is the VM doing and where it is hanging.

The garbage collection may not necessarily by the reason for the slowdown, it may be just suggesting that there is another operation that is taking too long and that is causing the GC. Check the thread dumpts to analyze the activity of the VM during that interval.

Comment: Can you explain more specifically how to use thread dumps while waking up the jboss server. I think thread dumps can be done to a working program to monitor its classes,objects and resource usage. My program is not working yet since my server is not alive at the moment of this long waiting time.

Comment: @alikerimerkan Generating a thread dump is possible just after your JVM starts. It doesn't matter your application already starts or is going to be up

Comment: Your VM instance is running, the fact that it is not doing anything does not mean that it is not running. You can take thread dumps of any running VM.